# What does the green background behind numbers mean in the "reputation" section of profiles?

Tags: support, reputation, profile-page

See this screenshot:

> [image]

The third [question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/63951/41775) has a green background behind the number. At first, I thought this meant [the answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/79338/41775) was accepted. (That's what it means in the "top posts" section.) However, in this example, the [answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/79338/41775) is *not* accepted.

So what does the green background mean?

Comment: Looks like the bounty has something to do with it?

Comment: @rene That's my only theory too, but I'm asking it here because I'm not sure.

Comment: I think it's a bug. Green background should mean that the answer is accepted.

Comment: @Gothdo I'll keep the [tag:support] tag until and if a mod agrees with you :)

Comment: It doesn't mean the answer is accepted it mean *that specific reputation gain* was from an acceptance (upvotes on already accepted answers don't get the background fill)... I'm assuming the same holds for bounty awards.

Comment: @Cai Right, because bounties and accepts go into the same "bucket" (the one that's unrelated to the daily rep cap). Is that what you mean? Sounds like a good theory.

Comment: very related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164176/307988

Answer (score 3):

Green background for the reputation gain in the Reputation section (**not reputation tab**) of the Activity tab of user's profile means that there is "bonus" reputation involved, i.e. not only from upvotes.

Types of such reputation:

- Answer was accepted
- Answer was awarded a bounty

Comment: Basically what I said, without the "I'm not sure so this is a theory" (which I'm now going to remove.... no one saw that right?) :)

Comment: @Cai Also, Shadow Wizard added a freehand circle to OP :) (which he may deserve extra points for.) But then again, your answer features freehand arrows.

Comment: @Fiksdal I knew my arrows weren't enough.... need to try harder

Comment: @Cai No, they're great. Keep in mind that SW's answer features **no** freehand objects whatsoever. But he did go the extra mile and add them to **my** post, which is admirable.

Comment: @Cai I know and thought twice before posting, but this answer is more simple/basic, without assumptions and without comparing it to the reputation tab. There is always the chance we're both wrong, but official answer might never arrive, so until then guess it's better to just have our answers around. :)

Comment: @Fiksdal my pleasure, I just have weird OCD when it concerns FHRC... ;-)

Comment: @Sha of course, no need to think twice :)

Comment: although I think comparing to the reputation tab *is* useful since the behaviour seems to be the same (except for the color difference)

Comment: @ShadowWizard What does R stand for? Free Hand Red Circles?

Comment: @Cai not sure it's the same, maybe it's a design choice: in the summary, use only green just to indicate reputation not from upvotes, and in the reputation tab itself, use different color for each event. (So that old bug you linked to might very well be [tag:status-bydesign])

Comment: @Fiksdal indeed! That's something I first saw here on Meta years ago, and got addicted. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Haha. One time I saw this otherwise great answer that had gotten a series of downvotes for using the "circle-tool", LOL.

Answer (score 1):

The green highlighting fill doesn't mean the answer itself is accepted, it (usually) means *that specific reputation gain* was from an acceptance. Much the same as it shows in the full reputation tab.

As you can see here:

[image]

I assume a bounty award gets that highlighting fill applied to the summary, just as it does in the the full reputation history.

Basically, anything that has the filled background in the reputation tab also gets it in the summary. The only difference being that bounties don't get styled differently (i.e. blue vs green) in the summary—probably just an oversight ([an old one, apparently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164176/307988)).

Comment: I think this seems like a good theory. (I think posting theories as answers for peer review is alright, too.) Though maybe you should highlight more (with bold or something) in the answer that it's indeed mainly a theory?

Comment: highlighted it, I'm pretty certain I'm correct though ([this seems to confirm it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164176/307988))

Comment: Yes, that does seem to corroborate it. It will be interesting to see a response from mods.

Comment: But see [this answer](http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/79338/1972) - it's not accepted yet the reputation gain from it appears green.

Comment: @ShadowWizard that's exactly what I was talking about... it's the *bounty* award that gets highlighted (the same as it does in the rep tab, but green instead of blue)

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164176/307988

Comment: I'm referring to "it means that specific reputation gain was from an acceptance" which begins the answer. :)

Comment: It normally does, with the exception of bounty awards, as I said in the last two paragraphs :)